# TCP IP socket communication in C. During the client exit, intimating server?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, udp

I am checking the communication between 2 entities (A and B) for their presence. A is a server and B is a client. When the server is up and running, it waits for connections and when B starts, it sends a message "Available" every one second. Now, the problem is, when I terminate the B program( ctrl+c or press the close button of the terminal), the server A does not recognise and still continues its operation. I would like for it to display message like "B is no more available" or "communicating partner is off". I understand TCP would be a best fit for the connection oriented communication. Please suggest me the changes to incorporate the display message on server A, when B is closed.
PS: amateur in socket programming

EDIT1: Managed to display the Message. However, since the server is designed to listen to many connections, I would like to make it accept the connections and not end the loop. Any guidance here would be useful.

**SERVER(A) TCP SERVER**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <string.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
    char buffer[256];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int  n;

    /* Initialize socket structure */
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = 5001;

    // create socket and get file descriptor
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    // bind the host address using bind() call
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
        perror("ERROR on binding\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // start listening for the clients,
    // here process will go in sleep mode and will wait for the incoming connection
    listen(sockfd, 5);

    // accept actual connection from the client
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clilen);

    // inside this while loop, implemented communication with read/write or send/recv function
    //printf("start");
    while (1) {
        bzero(buffer,256);
        n = read(newsockfd, buffer, 255);

        if (n < 0){
            perror("ERROR in reading from socket");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (n == 0){
            perror("Client has abruptly ended\n");
            close(sockfd);
            exit(1);
        }


        printf("client said: %s \n", buffer);

        n = write(newsockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));

        if (n < 0){
            perror("ERROR in writing to socket");
            exit(1);
        }

        // escape this loop, if the client sends message "quit"
       // if (!bcmp(buffer, "quit", 4))
        //    break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**CLIENT(B) TCP CLIENT**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];
    portno = 5001;

    // create socket and get file descriptor
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    server = gethostbyname("127.0.0.1");

    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);


    // connect to server with server address which is set above (serv_addr)

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("ERROR while connecting");
        exit(1);
    }

    // inside this while loop, implement communicating with read/write or send/recv function
    while (1) {
        strcpy(buffer,"Available");

        n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));

        if (n < 0){
            perror("ERROR while writing to socket");
            exit(1);
        }

        bzero(buffer,256);
        n = read(sockfd, buffer, 255);

        if (n < 0){
            perror("ERROR while reading from socket");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("server replied: %s \n", buffer);

        // escape this loop, if the server sends message "quit"

        //if (!bcmp(buffer, "quit", 4))
         //   break;
        
        sleep(1);   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please anybody tell me how to handle that issue?

Comment: Use `select` in server with a one second timeout to wait for `client` msg. If a full "Available" is not received (ie, `select` times out) then exit server.

Comment: Start by not using string functions. And **use the return value** you get from `read()` and `write()`.

Answer (score 2):

When the client closes the TCP connection, the server's call to `read(newsockfd)` will return 0 to indicate that the connection has closed.  At that point, the server should `close(newsockfd)`, print your "Client has gone away message", and not use `newsockfd` anymore (i.e. either the server program should exit, or, more usefully, it should just break out of its `while(1)`-loop and go back to calling `accept()` again, so that the next time a client runs it too can connect to the server)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer @Jeremy Friesner. I managed to exit the while loop. But it would be beneficial to get it to calling accept() again. I actually could not manage to get that done. I edited the code in the question. But how do we get it to accept connections again?

Comment: @RakshanPremsagarKapikad you'll need a second while loop outside the current one, so that when the current while(1) loop finishes, the outer while-loop brings the execution-point back up to `accept()` again

Comment: Thanks so much :)